# FFT Convolution

Tags: c#, performance, image, signal-processing

I have written the following routines to convolve two images in the frequency domain which are represented as 2d Complex arrays.

How can I optimize my routines for better performance?

```
public static class Convolution
{
    public static Complex[,] Convolve(Complex[,] image, Complex[,] mask)
    {
        Complex[,] convolve = null;

        int imageWidth = image.GetLength(0);
        int imageHeight = image.GetLength(1);

        int maskWidth = mask.GetLength(0);
        int maskeHeight = mask.GetLength(1);

        if (imageWidth == maskWidth && imageHeight == maskeHeight)
        {
            FourierTransform ftForImage = new FourierTransform(image); ftForImage.ForwardFFT();
            FourierTransform ftForMask = new FourierTransform(mask); ftForMask.ForwardFFT();

            Complex[,] fftImage = ftForImage.FourierImageComplex;
            Complex[,] fftKernel = ftForMask.FourierImageComplex;

            Complex[,] fftConvolved = new Complex[imageWidth, imageHeight];


            for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
                {
                    fftConvolved[i, j] = fftImage[i, j] * fftKernel[i, j];
                }
            }

            FourierTransform ftForConv = new FourierTransform();

            ftForConv.InverseFFT(fftConvolved);

            convolve = ftForConv.GrayscaleImageComplex;

            Rescale(convolve);

            convolve = FourierShifter.FFTShift(convolve);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("padding needed");
        }

        return convolve;
    }

    //Rescale values between 0 and 255.
    private static void Rescale(Complex[,] convolve)
    {
        int imageWidth = convolve.GetLength(0);
        int imageHeight = convolve.GetLength(1);

        double maxAmp = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
            {
                maxAmp = Math.Max(maxAmp, convolve[i, j].Magnitude);
            }
        }
        double scale = 255.0 / maxAmp;

        for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
            {
                convolve[i, j] = new Complex(convolve[i, j].Real * scale, convolve[i, j].Imaginary * scale);
                maxAmp = Math.Max(maxAmp, convolve[i, j].Magnitude);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few detail remarks:

```
Complex[,] convolve = null;
```

This variable declaration should be moved further down, to the line where it is actually needed. Initializing it with `null` is misleading.

```
maxAmp = Math.Max(maxAmp, convolve[i, j].Magnitude);
```

Since `Magnitude` involves a square root, it is expensive to calculate. Prefer calculating the square magnitude only and calculate the square root only once at the end. This saves `width * height - 1` square root calculations.

In the second loop, `maxAmp` is calculated again but never used. Removing it saves another `width * height` calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use anything from the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) yet?

You could try to parallelize one of the loops and see if the performance increases or drops: see [In a nested loop, should Parallel.For be used on the outer or inner loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11712934/235671)

Answer (score 2):

#### Question Review

- If you work with types that are not included in the standard .NET Framework, include the library and namespace for these types in the question: `FourierTransform`, `FourierShifter`, `Complex`.

#### Code Review

- Check arguments against null to avoid the nasty `NullReferenceException`.
- Give meaningful names to variables. Do not use `ft` and `fft` prefixes. This kills readability.
- Exit early on invalid state of the arguments. This simplifies the number of nested code blocks. Invert `if (imageWidth == maskWidth && imageHeight == maskHeight)` and throw error.
- Don't put multiple statements on a single line; `FourierTransform ftForMask = new FourierTransform(mask); ftForMask.ForwardFFT();`.
- Don't introduce unnecessary white lines between simple statements.
- Prefer the use of *var* for declaring variables.
- I presume `maskeHeight` has a typo in it -> `maskHeight`
- I don't see much room for optimizing the performance, since each step requires intermediate results from the previous one; perhaps as suggested in another answer, making one of the loops use `Parallel`, would benefit you.

If you use a certain pattern time and again, you might want to make a utility method for it. As suggested by Roland in the comments, we could implement a possible performance gain here. I would opt to call `AsParallel()` on the items. You could also try calling `Parallel.For` instead.

> ```
> for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
>     {
>         // do something ..
>     }
> }
> ```

```
static void Walk(int height, int width, Action<int, int> visit) 
{
    foreach (var point in (
             from j in Enumerable.Range(0, height)
             from i in Enumerable.Range(0, width) 
             select (i, j)).AsParallel())
    {
        visit(point.i, point.j);
    }
}
```

#### Method 'Convolve' refactored

```
public static Complex[,] Convolve(Complex[,] image, Complex[,] mask)
{
    image = image ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(image));
    mask = mask ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mask));

    var imageWidth = image.GetLength(0);
    var imageHeight = image.GetLength(1);
    var maskWidth = mask.GetLength(0);
    var maskHeight = mask.GetLength(1);

    if (!(imageWidth == maskWidth && imageHeight == maskHeight))
    {
        throw new Exception("padding needed");
    }

    var imageTransform = new FourierTransform(image);
    var maskTransform = new FourierTransform(mask);

    imageTransform.ForwardFFT();
    maskTransform.ForwardFFT();

    var imageComplex = imageTransform.FourierImageComplex;
    var maskComplex = maskTransform.FourierImageComplex;
    var convolvedComplex = new Complex[imageWidth, imageHeight];

    Walk(imageHeight, imageWidth, 
       (i, j) => convolvedComplex[i, j] = imageComplex[i, j] * maskComplex[i, j]);

    var convolvedTransform = new FourierTransform();
    convolvedTransform.InverseFFT(convolvedComplex);
    var convolve = convolvedTransform.GrayscaleImageComplex;
    Rescale(convolve);
    convolve = FourierShifter.FFTShift(convolve);

    return convolve;
}
```

Comment: Why add explicit code for `NullArgumentException` if it would be thrown anyway a few lines further down, unconditionally, easy to relate to the parameter?

Comment: Does your `Walk` function have any chance of being faster than a simple `for` loop? The OP asked about making the code a bit faster.

Comment: @RolandIllig (1) a few lines further a NullReferenceException would be thrown, which is harder to introspect than a NullArgumentException. It has a much more generic error message and less accurate stack trace.

Comment: @RolandIllig (2) valid point, the Parallel suggested by t3chb0t could be implemented here.